# How type safety is guaranteed?

Tags: rust

Just skimming through [the Rust guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/guide.html) (guessing game), this code fragment doesn't seem right to me:

```
let num = match input_num {
    Some(num) => num,
    None      => {
        println!("Please input a number!");
        continue;
    }
};
```

How does type inference of `num` work in this scenario? The first match case obviously return a number, whereas the second match case is just `println` & `continue` statement, which doesn't return anything(or return `()`). How does the compiler assume it's type safe?

Comment: We do not seem to have the same definition of type-safety. You seem here to be talking about type *inference* (guessing the right type) whereas type-safety is a property of a language which prevents you from observing a value of a given type as if it were of another, unrelated, type; the typical example of type unsafety is C's `void*`.

Comment: from a novice perspective, the first case of match expression returns "num" (ie uint value) whereas the second match expression returns "()"(since, the block is terminated with ";"), from my view the code is mixing two different type (uint type and () type) to a same variable.

Comment: I understand your view, it does not mean however that this is not typesafe as long as, in this case, the compiler records the type of `num` as being *either `uint` or `()`* and the only allow relevant manipulations. Of course, as explained in answers (but not something you can know before learning) it's actually a bit more magic :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's look at that piece of code more closely:

```
loop {
    // ... some code omitted ...
    let num = match input_num {
        Some(num) => num,
        None      => {
            println!("Please input a number!");
            continue;
        }
    };
    // ... some code omitted ...
}
```

The match statement is located inside a loop, and there are several constructs in the language which help control the looping process. `break` exits from a loop early, while `continue` skips the rest of the code in the loop and goes back to its beginning (restarts it). So this match above basically can be read basically as "Check the number, and if it is there, assign it to `num` variable, otherwise output a message and restart from the beginning".

The behavior of "otherwise" branch is important: it ends with a control transfer operation, `continue` in this case. The compiler sees `continue` and knows that the loop is going to be restarted. Consequently, it does not really matter what value this branch yields, because it will never be used! It may as well never yield anything.

Such behavior often is modeled with so-called [*bottom type*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), which is a subtype of any type and which does not have values at all. Rust does not have subtyping (essentially), so such type is deeply magical. It is denoted as `!` in type signatures:

```
fn always_panic() -> ! {
    panic!("oops!")
}
```

This function always panics, which causes stack unwinding and eventual termination of the thread it was called in, so its return value, if there was one, will never be read or otherwise inspected, so it is absolutely safe not to return anything at all, even if it is used in expression context which expects some concrete type:

```
let value: int = always_panic();
```

Because `always_panic()` has return type `!`, the compiler knows that it is not going to return anything (in this case because `always_panic()` starts stack unwinding), it is safe to allow it to be used in place of any type - after all, the value, even if it was there, is never going to be used.

`continue` works exactly in the same way, but locally. `None` branch "returns" type `!`, but `Some` branch returns value of some concrete numeric type, so the whole match statement is of this numeric type, because the compiler knows that `None` branch will lead to control transfer, and its result, even if it had one, will never be used.

Answer (score 8):

`continue` is, along with `break` and `return`, "divergent".  That is, the compiler knows that control flow does not resume after it, it goes somewhere else.  This is also true of any function which returns `!`; this is how the compiler knows that functions like `std::rt::begin_unwind` never return.

Comment: Note, `!` is the literature generally called *bottom*, see the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).